# Close file after ReadAllBytes

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, system.io.file

I want to convert a file to byte[] and then save it. but while saving it says that file is in use. how should I close the file after reading it as byte?

```
  void Function(string UploadPath, RadAsyncUpload RadAsyncUploadName)
    {
        foreach (UploadedFile file in RadAsyncUploadName.UploadedFiles)
        {
            FileStream tmpFile = (FileStream)file.InputStream;
            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(tmpFile.Name);
            //close the file here
            Function2(data);
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(UploadPath)+file.GetName());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the filestream -- just use the file name with readallbytes.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have read all the bytes in the stream, it looks like you cannot use the UploadedFile.SaveAs anymore. I would first SaveAs, then open the saved file an read it. Alternatively,  you can write back the byte array to the file you intended to save the data to.

Comment: good idea... but you mean there is no way to close the file after reading it as byte? may be some process should have been done before save as.

Comment: Looks like you are using Telerik framework Which abstracts things away. You would havd to read the docs to find out what's going on behind the scenes.